# How to get response headers in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
x = r.post(url="https://example.com",headers=H1,data=D1)
print(x.request.headers)
```

I'm trying to print out the received headers from the post request, how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way you print requests response headers:

`print(x.headers)`